# Can't load Skuli library

Tags: java, automated-tests, ui-automation, sikuli

I am encountering an exception when trying to execute following java code:

```
package testSikuliPackage;
import org.sikuli.script.*;
public class MyFirstSikuliTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed {
    float similarity = (float) 0.8;
    int timeout = 5;
    Pattern winStartBtn = new Pattern("img/start.PNG");
    Screen s = new Screen();
    if (s.exists(winStartBtn.similar(similarity), timeout) != null) {
      try {
        s.click(winStartBtn, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
}
```

I have ensured that Java 32 bit is used. Ensured that Environment variables for java and sikuli are set correctly. Not able to figure out what is wrong exactly!

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplib\VisionProxy.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
  at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
  at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
  at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
  at com.wapmx.nativeutils.jniloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:44)
  at org.sikuli.script.Finder.<clinit>(Finder.java:33)
  at org.sikuli.script.Regi...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am Sorry.. I fixed this issue. It was with the environment variables. Had missed a ";"...

For others if you encounter similar issue, Please try this...

1. Set SIKULI_HOME_home path
2. Set JAVA_HOME (Ensure java is 32 bit version)
3. Set your Path = %Path%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SIKULI_HOME%\libs;

And tadaa.. It should work..!
Thanks.